# Which decade was this US Army Field Artillery ring created?

Tags: military, identification

[image: The image is of a US Army Field Artillery ring being held in my fingers]

This is a US Army Field Artillery ring, does anyone know which decade it was made?

Comment: Do you have pictures of both sides? and the inside?

Comment: Quite similar to the item from [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/58898/16951).

Comment: This type ring is a private purchase item, primarily commemorating or celebrating one’s service.  They could be purchased at off-post emporiums, via mail order, the internet or even at the Purse Exterminator.  Not at all official, just a nice little commemorative item. A typical design from as far back as the 1920s, if not earlier, and up to the present day; available in designs for any branch of service and even for specific units.  Modern varieties tend to be a little flashier.  Google "field artillery ring" for modern internet offers.  Were I to guess, I would peg yours as WW2 vintage.